Mypy throwing error in mapping with union
I have dictionary:
example: dict[str, Union[str, int]] = {"foo": 1, "bar": "baz"}

Values are strings and integers. When I try to use values from it I definitely know what type of data I get from a particular key. But mypy doesn't know value, that i want to use is a string or integer.
For example, I want to compare int value with another int
res: bool = example["foo"] > 1

I understand why mypy says "Unsupported operand types for > ("str" and "int")", but I want to ignore this errors. What can I do?
I think Any type won't be best solution. Maybe I can configure mypy to ignore this errors?
Sorry for my bad english, thanks)

This question is similar to: Type hint for dictionary with known keys. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

If the dictionary is going to have the same keys every time, you can used a TypedDict
from typing import TypedDict

class ExampleType(TypedDict):
    foo: int
    bar: str


example: ExampleType = {'foo': 1, 'bar': 'baz'}
res: bool = example['foo'] > 1

